# How to enable programmatic access for a gallery image in Azure subscription?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-marketplace, azure-lab-services

Iam trying to create a Ubuntu server lab using Azure Lab Services account and followed the below steps.

In [image: screenshot 1], I have already enabled the Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS in Lab Services – Marketplace images.

In [image: screenshot 2], enabled marketplace image is listed in lab setup page

In [image: screenshot 3], Error:  The gallery image 'ubuntu server 18_04 lts' must be enabled for programmatic access in this subscription.

Can anyone help me how to resolve this error - "The gallery image 'ubuntu server 18_04 lts' must be enabled for programmatic access in this subscription."

Also, there is no option like "**Want to deploy programmatically?**" on the Ubuntu marketplace image page, attached the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot-4]

Answer (score 1):

I checked myself and have the same problem with Ubuntu 18.04LTS and 16.04LTS. However it works with Ubuntu 19.04 or other Windows images, so it seems there are problems with those images in Azure

I'd suggest you raise a ticket from your subscription or contact them via twitter @AzureSupport. Meanwhile, You may use that Ubuntu 19.04 if it works as a workaround

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Microsoft confirmed the issue and forwarded to their internal product teams. Here is the link.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/999e4cce-1932-4fa5-b739-6dc6f37a0ced/how-to-enable-programmatic-access-for-a-gallery-image-in-azure-subscription?forum=AzureDevTestLabs

Answer (score 0):

You can try these links:

- From portal (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/working-with-marketplace-images-on-azure-resource-manager/) you'd need to go to the image in marketplace and enable it for the subscription you're using looking for the *"Want to deploy programmatically?"* option (maybe you have more than one?) 
  [image]
- From CLI or PowerShell you might try this: https://blog.turtlesystems.co.uk/2018/10/16/Enabling-Programmatic-Access-in-Azure/

Comment: There is no option like "Want to deploy programmatically?" on the Ubuntu marketplace image page, updated the question with that screenshot as well, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again Bhanu for surfacing the issue. Our Internal product team was already working on fixing the issue.

The issue should be resolved now, you should be able to create the VM's in the lab with Ubuntu 18.04LTS/16.04LTS images.